# Google now travel time updates

Tags: google, google-maps, google-now, google-pixel, google-assistant

I use a google pixel and yesterday, google now asked if I'm interested in travel time updates to a shopping mall I recently visited and I happened to tap on 'yes'. Now, it shows me the ETA to that place all the time. I wish to disable ETA for this place now.

I'm pretty sure this feature was available as a yes/no questionier in google now > customize > everything else. But at the moment I do not see it. Has it moved elsewhere? Anyone having insight on this, please help.